# One view an array regardless of type (string[], decimal[] etc.)

Tags: c#, arrays, view, types

I know how to enumerate an array but how do I do so regardless of type?

Code:

```
ViewArray(saClosestVehicles);
```

```
public static void ViewArray(object[] ar) {
    #region Examples (Quickly display an arrays contents)
    // object[] ar = new object[] { "blah", 4, "whatever" }; 
    // ViewArray(ar); 
    #endregion

    string strArrayContents="";
    for(int cnt=0; cnt<ar.Length; cnt++)
        strArrayContents+=ar[cnt]+" ";

    MessageBox.Show(strArrayContents, "Array Contents");
}
```

Comment: what you have tried? I modified your question. Please visit the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) page if you have any time.

Answer (score 0):

```
object[] objArray = new object[]{"blah", 4, "whatever"};

foreach(var value in objArray)
{
    // do something with value
}
```

this what you want?

Comment: Assuming I am creating a method to view the array and I am passing a decimal array that would give me a 'Cannot convert decimal[] to string[]'.   

Hence: ViewArray(saClosestVehicles);

public static void ViewArray(object[] ar)
{
 #region Examples (Quickly display an arrays contents)
 //object[] ar = new object[] { "blah", 4, "whatever" };
 //ViewArray(ar);
 #endregion

 string strArrayContents = "";
 for (int cnt = 0; cnt < ar.Length; cnt++)
  strArrayContents += ar[cnt] + " ";
 MessageBox.Show(strArrayContents, "Array Contents");
}

Answer (score 0):

Consider generic declaration:

```
public static void ViewArray<T>(T[] ar) {
    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", ar.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()), "Array Contents");
}
```

Comment: Worked great Ken. Thanks!!